# Importing an ASP.NET website application to views in an MVC application

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have created an ASP.NET website with several aspx webpages and a masterpage. I now want to port this website to an MVC application and use the aspx pages as views. How can I do this in Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automatic process you can use to do this. You will need to create the views/controllers/actions manually and cut/paste your existing code into these (unfortunately)

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'm amazed that there's no out of the box method to do this since there's so much else in Visual Studio, I hope that they plan to include it in Visual Studio 2013 :)

Comment: You have to understand that the underlying structure of MVC is completely different to standard asp pages. I would love to see this kind of feature, but in all honesty, I would not hold my breath.

Answer (score 1):

Their is no one click process. You need to do it manually.

I suggest you to create a MVC solution. put your logic in Models, And start rewriting Controllers and Views according to your previous asp.net apps. Because asp.net MVC 's rules doesn't allow Session and Viewstate you need to make changes to your existing apps.

You need to move from session and Viewstate if your current asp.net app use this things.